# Radio button Show/Hide on parent element on page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In the below code, show/hide is not happening on page reload. If I check another radio button after page reloading, it's working. Help me to resolve the same.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $("[name=image_type]").on("change",imageTypeToggle);
})

function imageTypeToggle(){
    let selectedValue, $showElements, $hideElements;
    selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $hideElements = $(this).parents(".image_video_sec").find(".image_sec, .video_sec");
    $hideElements.hide().find("input").attr('disabled',true); 

    if(selectedValue == "0") {
        $showElements = $(this).parents(".image_video_sec").find(".image_sec");     
    } else if(selectedValue == "1") {
        $showElements = $(this).parents(".image_video_sec").find(".video_sec");
    }
    $showElements.show().find("input").attr('disabled',false); 
};
```

```html
<div class="image_video_sec">
  <label class="on">
      <input type="radio" name="image_type" value="0" checked>R1
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="image_type" value="1">R1
    </label>
     <dl class="image_sec">Image</dl>
     <dl class="video_sec">Video</dl>
</div>
<div class="image_video_sec">
  <label class="on">
      <input type="radio" name="image_type" value="0" checked>R1
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="image_type" value="1">R1
    </label>
     <dl class="image_sec">Image</dl>
     <dl class="video_sec">Video</dl>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to trigger a click on the radio button when the document loads. (I changed your `$(window).load` (which was throwing an error) to `$(document).ready`.

```
$("[name=image_type]").eq(0).trigger('click')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[name=image_type]").on("change", imageTypeToggle);
  $(".image_video_sec").each(function() {
    $(this).find("[name=image_type]").eq(0).trigger('click')
  })
})

function imageTypeToggle() {
  let selectedValue, $showElements, $hideElements;
  selectedValue = $(this).val();
  $hideElements = $(this).parents(".image_video_sec").find(".image_sec, .video_sec");
  $hideElements.hide().find("input").attr('disabled', true);
  if (selectedValue == "0") {
    $showElements = $(this).parents(".image_video_sec").find(".image_sec");
  } else if (selectedValue == "1") {
    $showElements = $(this).parents(".image_video_sec").find(".video_sec");
  }
  $showElements.show().find("input").attr('disabled', false);
};
```

```css
.image_sec,
.video_sec {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image_video_sec">
  <label class="on">
      <input type="radio" name="image_type" value="0" checked>R1
    </label>
  <label>
      <input type="radio" name="image_type" value="1">R1
    </label>
  <dl class="image_sec">Image</dl>
  <dl class="video_sec">Video</dl>
</div>
<div class="image_video_sec">
  <label class="on">
      <input type="radio" name="image_type" value="0" checked>R1
    </label>
  <label>
      <input type="radio" name="image_type" value="1">R1
    </label>
  <dl class="image_sec">Image</dl>
  <dl class="video_sec">Video</dl>
</div>
```

Comment: The above code isn't working if I have multiple div "image_video_sec" with the same radio button values as above. Could you please modify it?

Comment: @Naveen - my answer= has been updated to be modular for any number of  'image_video_sec'